# System.ArgumentException error when installing Lambda Test Tools

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

When I run the following command:
`dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.TestTool-6.0`

I get this error:
`Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or an empty string. (Parameter 'value') at NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion.Parse(String value)`

I tried the following:

- Installing dotnet 6.0 and verifying it's installed using `dotnet --list-sdks`
- Restarting my machine
- Creating a folder in ../.dotnet/ called 'tools'
- Clearing NuGet cache using `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`

Exception:
`` Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or an empty string. (Parameter 'value') at NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion.Parse(String value) at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.GetMetadataAsync(String packageId, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, VersionRange range, SourceCacheContext sourceCacheContext, ILogger log, CancellationToken token) at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.GetMetadataAsync(String packageId, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, SourceCacheContext sourceCacheContext, ILogger log, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetPackageMetadataAsync(PackageSource source, String packageIdentifier, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetMatchingVersionInternalAsync(String packageIdentifier, IEnumerable`1 packageSources, VersionRange versionRange, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetBestPackageVersionAsync(PackageId packageId, VersionRange versionRange, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.ToolPackage.ToolPackageDownloader.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<InstallPackage>b__0() at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.TransactionalAction.Run[T](Func`1 action, Action commit, Action rollback) at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.Execute() at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.Invoke(ParseResult parseResult) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient) ``

Comment: Its working fine for me. Try to run it from a different directory.

Comment: @AnkushJain I've tried that. Same issue...

Comment: can you please share a screenshot in the question?

Comment: @AnkushJain I've added the picture.

Comment: Please update the image with the command you run.

Comment: Also, try to run `dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools` this. If you still get the error, then it must be a local issue, not related to package.

Comment: @AnkushJain Same issue with the new command. The original command I ran is `dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do not include code, even if inner exception info as image. Why? because, to help you, maybe someone needs to copy some reference, or as in my case, the image has distorted text (word **include** is split like **incl** at right and next line **ude** at left); very confuse...

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated the picture to all text. I have also tried reinstalling the dotnet sdk's which didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by deleting Visual Studio via the Visual Studio Installer application and specifically installing the .NET SDK through the official website and everything worked.